# Seam application RichFaces not loading components

Tags: linux, tomcat, jboss, richfaces, seam

I have a Seam application running on:

- Linux CentOS
- Tomcat 6.0.32
- Java 6
- JBoss Seam 2.2.1
- RichFaces 3.3.3

When I run my application locally, everything works fine (Windows 7 here).  But when I put the exactly same files on my server (VPS), the Tomcat starts with no errors, but the **application do not load RichFaces components**.

I've searching the solution for this problem for a few days, but didn't found nothing that can help me.  I thought could be a permission problem (application's folder permission), so I've tried to change it too many ways, but RF components keep not loading.

Anyone can imagine what is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Fabricio Braga

Comment: Can you please post your tomcat logs?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.  The point is that in my case I have an Apache HTTP Server before Tomcat, and RichFaces add some JS files from JAR files.  So, we need to map, editing apache config files to redirect also this JS files to Tomcat.

Then, I just edited this Apache mappings to point RichFaces JS files to Tomcat, for example:

"/my-domain-name/a4j/g/3_3_3.Final/org/ajax4jsf/framework.pack.js" mapped there: "/my-domain-name/a4j/*" for the Tomcat.  And the same for the others files.

After that, the problem was over.

Regards,
Fabricio Braga